# Filter records based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, php, filtering

I am creating a form where a dropdown list will be generated based on the selection of a radio button.

[image: Form image]

Journal names are stored in a table with type as 1 or 2. When the radio button Journal is chosen, filter for journal type will be 1 and for the other it will be 2. I am using following code to generate the form.

```
<?php 
    $ctype = 1 // $ctype created for filtering purpose
?>

<p> Article For: 
    Journal <input type="radio" name="article_for" value="Journal" id="article_journal" /> 
    Conference <input type="radio" name="article_for" value="Conference" id="article_conference" />
</p>

<?php
    // $ctype will depend upon selection from radio button. If selection is "Journal"
    // value of $ctype to set 1 otherwise to set 2.
    $selectrecord = "SELECT `content_id`, `content_type`, `content_name` FROM `content` where `content_type` = $ctype";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$selectrecord) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
?>

<p> Journal Name: 
    <select name='content_id'>
        <?php
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                unset($id, $name);
                $id = $row['content_id'];
                $name = $row['content_name']; 
                echo '<option value="'.$id.'">' . $name . '</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</p>
```

I can check the selected radio button with a code set like

```
if(document.getElementById('article_journal').checked) {
```

But in this if clause, I can not assign a value to the variable $ctype - which is being used to filter the names for the dropdown list.

Kindly help me find out what I am doing wrong.

Best regards.

Comment: It is not possible that way, because javascript is client side only, php server side only. What you are looking for is __ajax__. Or you can send the form and reload the page to get the matching values (easier, but not as user-friendly).

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, it also came to me as I may not be thinking in the right way. Thanks for the clue.

Comment: So best way is to start an ajax-call when one of the radios change. Call a php-script with the selected value, generate the desired list in php-script and recieve that in ajax-success callback, then insert into html.

Comment: If the dropdown lists are not too long you can also create them both on page load and hide one of them. You can then switch the `hide` and `show` around using simple javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I decided to create multiple pages where related fields are physically situated in the form quite a distant. POST variables solved the issue. Where they are adjacent to each other, I used jQuery to filter the options.

Comment: My issue is solved, but I don't know how to mark this question as "Solved".